# chrome displaying correctly the view, but saying "notice: undefined variable..." in source code when I inspect it. How to fix?

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-chrome

PHP/HTML code

```html
<td width="12%" align="right" bgcolor="#F5E4A9">TITOLO</td>
<td width="88%" bgcolor="#F5E4A9"><input name="pagetitle" type="text" id="pagetitle" size="80" maxlength="255" value="<?php echo $pagetitle; ?>" onkeyup="getTitle()"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td align="right" bgcolor="#D7EECC">SOTTOTITOLO<br>(facoltativo)</td>
   <td bgcolor="#D7EECC"><input name="linklabel" type="text" id="linklabel" size="80" maxlength="255"  value="<?php echo $linklabel; ?>" onkeyup="content()"/>(se riempito, sar&agrave; utilizzato anche come anteprima per GOOGLE)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td align="right" valign="top" bgcolor="#DAEAFA">TESTO</td>
   <td bgcolor="#DAEAFA" valign="top" align="center">
      <textarea name="pagebody" id="pagebody" class="MCEeditor" cols="88" rows="16" onkeyup="getPagebody()">
      <?php echo $pagebody; ?>
      </textarea>
   </td>
```

[rendering by chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNaeP.jpg)

[source code according to chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqdJb.jpg)

And I think It gets some of my scripts not to work because they come back to work when I remove notice notifications and put rendered values in their place.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question?

Comment: I attached two images because I realize it's quite weird

Answer (score 1):

This just means that the variables you have used is not defined. This is either because of a typo or that you have not created the variables

**EDIT:**

As Frithjof mentions;
The scope you are rendering to the  is not aware of $pageBody. If you have defined $pageBody in the global scope and the html rendering is done in a function, you have to use the variables in a special way. Check out this link about (variable) scopes and read more on your favorite php tutorial [website](http://w3schools.com/php/php_superglobals.asp). Anyway, global variables are not best practice. You should avoid using them wherever you can. Parsing variables via parameters is better

Comment: uhm, may you please make an example?

Comment: I mean, the value of the variables is echoed correctly, such that I can see them in the "front end", vut when I right click>view source code I find notice messages instead of them...

Comment: Are you sure the browser does not use the cached source code?

Comment: The error / notice you get is quite clear: The scope you are rendering the $pageBody to the <textarea> is not aware of $pageBody. Are you sure that the file / function is accessible? If you defined $pageBody in the global scope and the html rendering is done in a function, you have to use them in a special way. Check out this link about (variable) scopes and read more on your favorite php tutorial website: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_superglobals.asp. Anyway, global variables are not best practice. You should avoid using them wherever you can. Passing variables via parameters is better